# Can't default date to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql-5.5, timestamp, date, default-value

I am not able to set `Current_timestamp` as default value. My `Mysql` version is `5.5.47`.

Query is

```
ALTER TABLE `downloads` ADD `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

[image]

While it is working fine on my local DB with `mysql V5.6.56`.

Comment: The problem is due to microseconds added in default value in mysql new versions. See http://tekina.info/default-datetime-timestamp-issue-mysql-upgrading-5-6/ for solutions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [MySQL 5.5 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> You cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a
>   function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can
>   specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

Therefore, what you want to achieve will work in MySQL 5.5 if you add a `TIMESTAMP` column instead of a `DATE` column.

The changes in 5.6.x that allow the functionality are documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html), and I'll quote the relevant summary for completeness:

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
>   for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.

Answer (score 12):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168832/342196).

Your options are:

- Upgrade to MySQL 5.6.5
- Change the column type to TIMESTAMP, as in:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `downloads` ADD `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
  ```
- Create a TRIGGER THAT updates the column automatically:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `downloads` ADD `date` DATETIME NULL; -- date must allow
                                                    -- NULLs or default
                                                    -- to a special value
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS downloads_BI;
  DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER downloads_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON downloads FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      IF (NEW.date IS NULL) THEN -- change the isnull check for the default used
          SET NEW.date = now();
      END IF;
  END//
  DELIMITER ;
  ```

  You may want to create an update value, too, if it must be automatically updated on update or want to prevent null values.

  ```
  mysql> INSERT INTO downloads (i) VALUES (1); -- I do not set date
  Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

  mysql> SELECT * FROM downloads;
  +------+---------------------+
  | i    | date                |
  +------+---------------------+
  |    1 | 2016-03-22 09:27:52 |
  +------+---------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```